# Recover a deleted blogger template

Tags: blogger

By mistake, a friend of mine changed the template of her blog and is not being able to recover the old style.

The actual template is [here](http://www.blogdestinoamiami.com/) and she wants to recover to this 
[one](http://web.archive.org/web/20161015165307/http://www.blogdestinoamiami.com/)

**Is it possible to recover the old template if she didn't have any bakup?**

Comment: There is no way, But any blogger designer can recover it from web archive source code.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery of older template is possible only if you have kept a back up of earlier template which you were using.

If you don't have that template then the back up is not possible.

Regards,
MJ Haider